# PHP modify RegEx

Tags: php, regex

I have pattern:

```
/^(?:{?[a-z0-9\-_]+\??}?\/)+$/
```

Now these strings match the pattern

```
user/1/modify/
user/{id}/modify/
user/{id?}/modify/
```

It's OK, but now this pattern match

```
user/{id?/modify/
```

If the left curly brace start it must end with right. I tried with lookahead but i dont't know it is right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
^(?:(?:{\w+\??}|\w+)\/)+$
```

https://regex101.com/r/yO3pA5/1

It tries to match anything in the set `[A-Za-z0-9_]` followed by optional `?` inside `{}`s, and then it tries to match the same set *without* the `{}`s (and optional `?`, but you can add that back in), followed by a `/`.  That way it won't allow for unclosed braces.

Comment: The easiest way is the best :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a positive lookahead to the first conditional match to ensure the closing bracket is there:

```
^(?:(?:{(?=[\w-]+\??}))?[\w-]+\??}?\/)+$
```

(`[\w-]` is equivalent to `[a-z0-9\-_]`)

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/fK8fX0/1)